# Why after refreshing page getting undefined result form api?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, redux, axios

I am a beginner and trying to make a photo gallery. I am using pexels api to get photos. When I first time write the code of fetch image I am getting result correctly. But if refresh the page, I am getting **undefined**. I checked the **error** state and it is null. Actually the thing is happening when I am **mapping** the images. But if I comment out the mapping code, then getting the photos on the console without any error.

**Here is a video:** [Problem video | Gdrive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CX__uij4MSt4H4BbKC9IrLWa49X4jQzY/view?usp=sharing)

**imageSlice.js**

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import axios from 'axios';

const initialState = {
  images: [],
  error: null,
  isLoading: false,
};

const config = {
  Authorization: '563492ad6f91700001000001350d302e175b4c208aac413953d6edcc',
};

export const fetchImages = createAsyncThunk('images/fetchImages', async () => {
  const res = await axios.get(
    'https://api.pexels.com/v1/search?query=nature&per_page=15',
    {
      headers: config,
    }
  );
  console.log('Axios:', res.data);
  return res.data;
});

export const imageSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'images',
  initialState,
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder.addCase(fetchImages.pending, state => {
      state.isLoading = true;
    });
    builder.addCase(fetchImages.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.images = action.payload;
      state.error = null;
    });
    builder.addCase(fetchImages.rejected, (state, action) => {
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.images = [];
      state.error = action.error.message;
    });
  },
});

// export const {} = imageSlice.actions;

export default imageSlice.reducer;
```

**store.js**

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import imageReducer from './imageSlice';

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    images: imageReducer,
  },
});
```

**Images.jsx**

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchImages } from '../redux/imageSlice';
import Image from './Image';

const Images = () => {
  const { photos } = useSelector(state => state.images.images);
  const a = useSelector(state => console.log(state.images));

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchImages());
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h2>Images</h2>
      {photos.map(photo => (
        <Image key={photo.id} image={photo} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Images;
```

**Image.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

const Image = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col">
          <img src={props.image.src.medium} alt={props.image.alt} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Image;
```

Why this is happening? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Just change  :**

```
    return (
        <div className="container">
          <h2>Images</h2>
          {photos.map(photo => (
            <Image key={photo.id} image={photo} />
          ))}
        </

div>
  );
```

**to :**

```
return (
    <div className="container">
      <h2>Images</h2>
      {photos && photos.map(photo => (
        <Image key={photo.id} image={photo} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```